# Facebook Graph API - Post a remote image to an album

Tags: facebook-graph-api, curl

At the moment I have to download images on the server and post them like this:

```
$photo = array(
    'message'  => 'Status',
    'source'   => '@/full/path/of/the/image.png'
);

$response = $fb->api('/'.$album.'/photos', 'POST', $photo);
```

I'm using curl on the backend to post this request and it's working like a charm.
I'm wondering if it's possible to post the remote image directly instead to download a local copy?

I tried to do something like this:

```
$photo = array(
    'message'  => 'Status',
    'source'   => file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/image.png')
);

$response = $fb->api('/'.$album.'/photos', 'POST', $photo);
```

But I got an exception from the graph API: "(#324) Requires upload file"

It looks like this is happening when you are not sending the multipart/data header which is set automatically when sending an array of data (`$data` is an array).

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

So I'm doubtful that it's possible to post a remote image.
What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to upload a photo by just giving that photo’s URL under the parameter name `url`.

This info is a little hidden in the [description of the `photo` endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/), where it just says,

> *“You can also publish a photo by providing a url param with the photo's URL.”*

So instead of providing the `source`parameter, just provide `url` with the value of the photo’s publicly reachable URL. (All other parameters except `source` stay the same and are still usable in the same way.)

I tried this recently, and it worked fine. Although, I only tried it for photos with URLs from my app domain – I can’t say *for sure* if it works for URLs from “anywhere” on the web as well (although i can’t see a good reason for why it shouldn’t).

Comment: Nice ;) Thanks a lot for that. So much nicer :D